# Can I use coalesce with a binding expression in a variable in a custom SAQL query?

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, analytics-bindings

I'm writing a custom SAQL query with bindings in order to total some categories that are made in a list elsewhere on the dashboard. Here's my query so far; it has the same binding expression multiple times.

```
q = load "X20220526_135309";

myCounts = foreach q generate q.'name' as 'theName', 
    (case "category1" in {{column(count_of_gaps_1.selection, ["gapName"]).asString()}}
        when true then q.category1
        else 0
    end) as 'category1count',
    (case "category2" in {{column(count_of_gaps_1.selection, ["gapName"]).asString()}}
        when true then q.category2
        else 0
    end) as 'category2count'
;

result = filter gapCounts by category1count > 0 || category2count > 0;
result = order result by oneSetup  desc;
```

However, the binding returns NULL if no selections are made, and the query errors: "Right hand side of IN should be all or array, got NULL"

Can I consolidate the binding into a single place somehow, to handle the null case, and to do any validation? I've tried to create that variable:

```
mySelection = coalesce( {{column(count_of_gaps_1.selection, ["gapName"]).asString()}}, []);
```

But now the query gives me an error related to coalesce, or maybe null:

```
Syntax Error at position [line 3: column 24] after token ( :: 
on = coalesce( null, []);
```

I've also tried to do the coalesce() inside the binding:

```
mySelection = {{coalesce(column(count_of_gaps_1.selection, ["gapName"]), []).asString()}};
```

But that gives a different error:

```
coalesce(*, *).asString()
    **coalesce(column(*, *), [])** => Expected 1 but given 2 arguments.
        column(count_of_gaps_1.selection, [*])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use coalesce inside the binding, but by quoting the default value. This statement generates `q.category1` count when category1 is selected, and zero otherwise. The important part is `"[]"` to default to an empty array.

```
myCounts = foreach q generate q.'name' as 'theName', 
    (case "category1" in {{coalesce(column(count_of_gaps_1.selection, ["gapName"]), "[]").asString()}}
        when true then q.category1
        else 0
    end) as 'category1Count';
```